# How to get on fly while text input is completed

Tags: javascript

I need to get (on fly, not while submitting the form) if an input text is completed or not, to have a javascript confirmation on submitting button.

The input is `<input type="text" name="first" value="" />`

The submitting button is `"<input type="submit" name="submit" />`

In this button, I would like a JavaScript script to confirm popup when the field "first" is empty, like `onclick="return(confirm('Are you sure ?')"`
I don't want to have any confirm while the field is filled.

I know how to control after submitting button, but not before.
I think I have to use AJAX to pass a variable through the form to get the correct value, but I don't know to achieve this.

Comment: tried `onkeyup()`?

Comment: You want to notify the user when he pressed Submit or when?

Comment: why the php tag though?

Comment: Probably new to web development.

Comment: Yes, i'm pretty new to web developpment.

Comment: I want to notify when submitting form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more code to onclick handler (check the text and if it's empty return confirmation state).

```js
document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
  if (!text) {
    // run only text is falthy (empty string, null, undefined etc)
    return confirm('Are you sure ?');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="first" id='textInput' value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id='submitButton'/>
</form>
```

More variants how to add click handler you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_onclick.asp):